# Export SQL Server data to Excel in a web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ajax, excel

I would like to export data from a SQL Server pull (usually I use `SqlDataReader`, but am open to suggestions) into an Excel/CSV file and have the user of the web app get it as a download.

I'd like to do this AJAX style, so that the click on download won't cause a reload/postback.

Anyone done this before or have an idea on how?

Comment: You're going to have issues with a web app & Excel.  Try this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/11559077/61339

Comment: @JeffO I'm fine with a csv. I'm still not sure how to work the download on click though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this mechanism would work.

Have an HTML button that calls a javascript function when clicked.

```
<input id="downloadbtn" type="button" value="Download" onclick="download();" />
```

Function would look something like this:

```
var download = function() {
  $.ajax({
  url: "datamaker.aspx",
  context: document.body
  }).done(function(data) { 
    //  parse response data, get file path
    var filepath = ParseDataToGetFilePath(data);

    // open the csv file path in a new window (which will begin download)
    window.open(filepath, '_blank');
  });

};
```

In the serverside, "datamaker.aspx" should connect to the SQL Server, and create the CSV file. Creating a CSV file is as easy as creating any other file using streamwriter, and writiing "comma" between fields. At the end of this page, output the filename either in a response xml or json.

```
     { filepath: \path\datafile.csv }
```